# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express: way to convert NULL's from Joins to zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables I'm trying to join in `SQL Server`.  Table one is a list of `salesId`'s and table two is a list of average sales per month by `salesId`.

Table1 :

```
SalesId
 0001
 0004
 0345
 1009
 2290
 ....
```

Table2:

```
SalesId    AvgMnthSales
 0001       22253.34
 0002        8970.28
 0003       15377.45
 0004         349.03
 0005        3498.44
 ....         ...
```

So I do a join like this:

```
Select t1.SalesId, t2.AvgMnthSales
from table1 t1
left join
table2 t2
on t1.SalesId = t2.SalesId
```

and get something like this:

```
   SalesId      AvgMnthSales
     0001        22253.34
     0004          349.03
     0345         NULL
     1009         NULL
     2290         8846.56
     ....          ....
```

What I'd prefer is to have any `NULL` converted to `0`.  I've seen some examples where this was done in a two step process of sending the results to a temp table and then converting `NULL`'s to `0`'s, but was curious if there's a single step way to do this.

The reason is largely due to ignorance.  I'm not sure how temp tables are handled (in `RAM` or on disk) and how much space they take up as this is a large data set and it would likely take up several `GB`'s of `RAM` or disk space.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select t1.SalesId, COALESCE(t2.AvgMnthSales,0) as AvgMnthSales
from table1 t1
left join
table2 t2
on t1.SalesId = t2.SalesId
```

Answer (score 4):

```
isnull(avgmnthsales,0)
```

Should work

Answer (score 4):

Use the COALESCE function:

```
Select t1.SalesId, coalesce(t2.AvgMnthSales, 0)
from table1 t1
left join
table2 t2
on t1.SalesId = t2.SalesId
```

Answer (score 2):

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) will return the first parameter that is not null.  For your case, it will return `t2.AvgMnthSales` unless it is NULL, at which point it would return the second parameter: 0

```
SELECT t1.SalesId, COALESCE(t2.AvgMnthSales, 0) AS AvgMnthSales
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.SalesId = t2.SalesId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE` or `IFNULL`:

```
Select t1.SalesId, COALESCE(t2.AvgMnthSales, 0) AS AvgMnthSales
from table1 t1
left join
table2 t2
on t1.SalesId = t2.SalesId
```

If you actually want *no* results for the `NULL` values, then use an `INNER JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`.